# Prevent UISwitch from changing the UI state

Tags: ios, swift, return, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` which executes an operation. I need to display an alert with yes/no options. If the user selects the option *No*, nothing should happen. The switch's UI shouldn't change.

Here's my code.

```
func toggleSwitchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This operation will reset the photos you have renamed already. Proceed?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel) { action in
        return
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action in
        self.api.includeCoverPhoto(sender.on)
    })
    alert.preferredAction = alert.actions[1]
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm firing this method on `UISwitch`'s value changed event.

The problem is if I select *No*, the operation doesn't proceed. But the `UISwitch`'s UI changed to the other state.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: you can just switch back to default state, that's what we usually do.

Comment: Yes, `sender.setOn(!sender.on, animated: true)` does work but I was hoping there was a way to stop it beforehand because it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 6):

```
    func toggleSwitchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This operation will reset the photos you have renamed already. Proceed?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel) { action in
             sender.setOn(true, animated:false)               
             return
    })
    ....
```

Answer (score 3):

The value changed action method gets called *after* the switch has changed, so you can't do it that way.

You will need to disable user interactions for the switch, then overlay a UIButton on top of it. Present your alert in the button's touch up inside action, or possibly the touch down depending on which you like better.

Then in your button action, show your alert and programmatically change the switch state.

Comment: There is a simple solution, check my answer, it gave me a lot of problems but it was that simple :D

Comment: Your solution doesn't stop the switch from changing state, it just changes the state back after the user cancels. My solution stops the button from changing state in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change switch.isOn parameter in switchValueChanged just to this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.switch.isOn = !sender.isOn // true or false
}
```

Comment: This one did it for me. It was necessary to do this in an async call to prevent the switch from keeping the user-set state.